# Check getopts argument

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script to combine multiple files into a single file. I have no idea the input/output files' names and how many input files are there, I decide to use -i flag to read input files and -o flag to specify output file.

Please note this is just the first step to read input/output files. I am dealing with input files in multiple formats: txt, xlsx, rtf, pdf. So a single `cat f1 f2 f3 > outfile` won't work in my case.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script merge txt,xlsx,rtf,pdf files in pdf_input folder into a single pdf file and save the output 
# file to pdf_output folder


usage () {
  echo "Script usage:"
  echo "  $0 -i <input file1>,<input file2>,<input file3>,... -o <combined output file>"
  echo "  If you have multiple input files, the file names need to be seperated by ,"
  exit
}

while getopts ":i:o:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        i)
          echo "Input file string = $OPTARG "
          set -f
          IFS=',' # split on space characters
          array=($OPTARG) # use the split+glob operator
          ;;
        o)
          echo "Output file = $OPTARG"
          ;;
        h)
          usage
          exit 0
          ;;
        :)
          echo "Error: -${OPTARG} requires an argument."
          usage
          exit 1
          ;;
        *)
          usage
          exit 1
          ;;
    esac
done

echo "Number of input files: ${#array[@]}"
echo -n "Input files are:"
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  echo -n " ${i} "
done
```

:) checks the empty argument well. However, if I combine both -o and -i flags, I am getting unexpected result.  Is there a way to check empty arguments on both flags?

```
#./pdf_merge.sh -i a,b,c,d -o out
Input file string = a,b,c,d
Output file = out
Number of input files: 4
Input files are: a  b  c  d

#./pdf_merge.sh -o
Error: -o requires an argument.
Script usage:
  ./pdf_merge.sh -i <input file1>,<input file2>,<input file3>,... -o <combined output file>
  If you have multiple input files, the file names need to be seperated by ,

#./pdf_merge.sh -i
Error: -i requires an argument.
Script usage:
  ./pdf_merge.sh -i <input file1>,<input file2>,<input file3>,... -o <combined output file>
  If you have multiple input files, the file names need to be seperated by ,

#./pdf_merge.sh -i -o
Input file string = -o
Number of input files: 1
Input files are: -o,

#./pdf_merge.sh -o -i
Output file = -i
Number of input files: 0
```

Comment: What if you have a file named `-o`?

Comment: `-i -o` - -- the argument to `-i` is `-o`, and vis versa with `-o -i`.

Comment: Why are you using `getopt` at all?  Instead of `pdf_merge.sh -i file1,file2,file3 -o outfile`, change the usage to be `pdf_merge.sh file1 file2 file3 outfile`

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr: `echo ERR... >&2`.  Usage statements are not error messages, and should not be emitted in addition to an error message.  Only write a usage statement when asked.  When you type `cmd --long-opton-name`, you want a single line error that says "unkown option: long-opton-name", not a 5 page output of all the possible option names.  Writing a usage statement in addition to an error message is line noise.

Comment: I would just change the calling order to `pdf_merge.sh outfile file1 file2 file3`. Then `outfile=$1; shift`, and the input files are just whatever is left in `"$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

I add a check mechanism on the arguments. It's not the cleanest solution, but this works.

```
while getopts ":i:o:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        i)
          echo "Input file string = $OPTARG "
          if [ "$OPTARG" == "-o" ]; then
            echo "Input error! You need to have at least one input file"
            usage
            exit 1
          fi
          set -f
          IFS=',' # split on space characters
          array=($OPTARG) # use the split+glob operator
          ;;
        o)
          echo "Output file = $OPTARG"
          if [ "$OPTARG" == "-i" ]; then
            echo "Input error! You need to specify an output file"
            usage
            exit 1
          fi
          ;;
        h)
          usage
          exit 0
          ;;
        :)
          echo "Error: -${OPTARG} requires an argument."
          usage
          exit 1
          ;;
        *)
          usage
          exit 1
          ;;
    esac
done
```

Thanks for everyone's input.